# Publicity link open when I am still testing my website locally

Tags: html

I developed a website with html ,I am testing it locally (using wampserver) until now ,my problem is some time when I click on a link (which is locally to redirect to another page on my website) another window of publicity is open ? I dont know why? 
what I mean is that there is sort of spam or somthing ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <title>TTS</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="css/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css" type="text/css" media="all" />



</head>
<body>
<div id="allscreen">
    <div id="thisCnt">
    <div class="imageScreen">
<a href="ar/homeArabe.html"><img src="css/images/d.png" onMouseOver="this.src='css/images/dMouseOver.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='css/images/ar.png';" alt="" /></a>
<a href="fr/home.html"><img src="css/images/fr.png" onMouseOver="this.src='css/images/frMouseOver.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='css/images/fr.png';" alt="" /></a>
<a href="home.html"><img src="css/images/en.png" onMouseOver="this.src='css/images/enMouseOver.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='css/images/en.png';" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @BenM I have added my code

Answer (score 1):

You have adware on your computer. Remove it with [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As BenM said, without seeing your code it is very difficult to answer.

Perhaps your target attribute is set to _blank.

Example:

```
 <a href="http://www.example.com/page.html" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

You can either remove this

```
target="_blank"
```

, or set it to

```
target="_self"
```

Best would be for you to show us your code.